# UKVI agreed to reconsider but I've heard nothing. Now what?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, bangladeshi-citizens

I am a Bangladeshi national and applied for a UK visit visa to visit the UK for 10 days. My husband is my sponsor. I am a business woman, have my own successful business in Bangladesh. I am also responsible for my ill health and elderly mother in Bangladesh.

In November 2022 I received a refusal letter, my application was refused under Refusal of UK Standard Visitor visa under v4.2(a)(c), v4.2 (e) and v4.3(a)(c). In November 2022 I submitted a Pre Action Protocol.

On 11 December 2022 I received a reply from UKVI stating as follows:
"I have reviewed the refusal notice and the decision to refuse is withdrawn in favour of a
reconsideration. Therefore, we will commence the reconsideration process within three
months from the date of this letter." However, it has  been over three months I have not received any update/correspondence from UKVI.

What should we do next?

Comment: Have you contacted UKVI for a progress update?

Comment: Hi Thank you for your reply, 3 month from the UKVI letter  was completed on 11 March 2023, I was asked by a friend to wait a few days so I am thinking of writing to them on this Friday. Do anyone have a sample letter I can use or should simple write to ask for an update. Thanks again for your help.